# Warning from Webpack after upgrade Next.js

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, next.js

JS app, just upgrade next to 10.1.2. Wanted to add webpack 5. Created a `next.config.js` and followed their instructions. But I'm getting a warning in the terminal in VScode.

[image]

Can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Talked with Tobias Koppers(Founder of webpack),
they will fix the problem after the holidays.
Only thing is that it won't use persistent caching.